# Send Email as Notification

Tags: android, email, notifications

Hey, i'm creating an application and would like to know, is there a way to automatically send an email from my application, lets say at 3:00, automatically without any input from the user. So instead of creating an intent to open gmail then user has to hit 'send' is there a way to just send it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all you need:

- [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/)
- [Using AlarmManager to Schedule Activities on Android](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129)

Comment: All users now call me "dear"... what's going on? XD

Comment: lol, I wasn't calling you dear, I was thanking you dearly haha :p, if you're really into android, hit me up on google talk sam.voss, I'm always looking to have more developer friends to help/be helped!

Comment: Hey... nice... just added you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so (I look forward to an answer that proves me wrong) but I think there are security concerns for that. BUT what I know you could do is make a webservice call that could send an e-mail (on behalf of the user) that has the reply-to set to the user's e-mail address.