# Manually check data before storing in SQL database

Tags: android, database, storage

I am writing an Android app that stores location-based data.  I want to prevent users from uploading incorrect or prank data.  I was wondering how this issue is usually handled.  Is this rare enough that people just check the newest data every few days for errors, or do they manually check the data before it is uploaded putting it in a type of quarantine?  By the way, I am not expecting too much data to be added, so manually checking is feasible.  If I quarantine the data how would I get it sent through e-mail?  I know this question is a little bit vague, but please share what is normally done in this situation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about sending them into a temporary database, which serves as a quarantine database, and then inserting them manually into the main database after the data has been checked.

For the e-mail notification, you could check this : [Send Email as Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463152/send-email-as-notification)

Create a check when a new location data is uploaded to the database, if a new data is successfully uploaded, send the email notification (and the location info, if you want).